# How can I ssh into a machine using python and create a persistent python session on that machine to send a series of commands?

Tags: python, ssh, pexpect

I have tried subprocces.Popen('ssh...') and pexpect.spawn and pxssh.pxssh().

So far everything I have tried seems to get stuck when I send a 'python -i' command. I assume this is because it's starting a process that doesn't terminate?

I would really like to create a persistent object so that I can send python commands that can be executed on the remote machine.

This should be possible right?

EDIT with Code example:

The following works:

```
from pexpect import pxssh

s = pxssh.pxssh(timeout=None)
s.login(hostname, username, password)
s.sendline('python -c "import somelibrary;somelibrary.call_function()"')
s.prompt()
print s.before
```

but this call never returns:

```
from pexpect import pxssh

s = pxssh.pxssh(timeout=None)
s.login(hostname, username, password)
s.sendline('python')
s.prompt()
print s.before
```

I'd like to have an open python session on the target machine so that I can import libraries once and then send subsequent commands and get the output

make sense?

Comment: Why would you not deploy the Python app on the target machine and execute locally from an ssh connection?

Comment: I am looking to do some automation where each machine is dependent on outcomes of the other machine. To do this I want to have one machine be the leader and the other the follower. So the leader will do something then based on the outcomes send some commands to the follower. It will read the results and then do something based on those results, so on and so forth. I can get it working with python -c commands but I was hoping to avoid repeating all the imports on every command I send.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code that you have for connecting to the remote system and starting python, even if it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Have you looked into minimizing your number of imports?  Is that a significant performance bottleneck for you?

Comment: it's a library that I need and it has some overhead when being imported. it's more of a bottle neck than it should be but I am not in a position to optimize it.